# how Inject/overrid code in function? best practice?

Tags: javascript, overriding, inject

I got a big js lib witch I dont want to change because when they update the code I must update every time as well. So I want to inject or override as little as possible. And get my code in.

The code of the lib and my code in it looks like this:

```
var Erizo = {}
Erizo.Stream = function (spec) {
    var that = Erizo.EventDispatcher(spec);

    that.init = function (succesCallBack) {
         Erizo.GetUserMedia(opt, function (stream) {
             [...]    
             MY CODE
             [...]
         }
    }
    [...]
}
```

Is there a way to inject my code and dont override the hole Erizo.Stream function? Because this function is very big.

Thanks

Comment: yes, but you can either do your code on the beginning or in the end, can´t choose somewhere on bewteen

Comment: ok thanks, whats the way on the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
var oldFunction = Erizo.GetUserMedia

Erizo.GetUserMedia = function(opt, callback){
    console.log("code injected")
    oldFunction.apply(this,[opt, callback])
}
```